# malloc string in c with the same size of original string

Tags: c, string, calloc

I have a string in my main functions.

I need to send it to other functions and make malloc to new string with the same size of the original.

I try something like this:

```
#define SIZE_STRING 100
typedef char string[SIZE_STRING];

char *testCode(string str)
{   
    char *new_str;
    int limit = strlen(str);
    int new_limit;
    new_str = (char*)calloc(limit, sizeof(char));
    new_limit = strlen(new_str);
    printf("%d", new_limit);

    return new_str;
}

void main()
{
    char str[SIZE_STRING] = { "BLA BLA BLA" };
    char *new_str;
    new_str=testCode(str);
}
```

The `new_limit` get the size of 0.

What should I do?

Comment: `char *testCode(string str)` What is string ? BTW: main() should return int.

Comment: typedef char string[SIZE_STRING];

Comment: just typdef of char, it will be string[100];

Comment: Why ? Why does main use `char str[SIZE_STRING] = { "BLA BLA BLA" };` again ?

Comment: Always use the language tag for proper highlighting, better categorization and to get the right eyes on it. Use the `edit`link to add it.

Comment: Writing a new version of [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html)?

Comment: Well i'm new here, it will be beter, thakns!

Comment: @wildplasser The problem is pretty obvious. How are you comments helpful?

Comment: They are comments. And they are helpful in the way that first #defining a pseudo-typedef, and subsequently _not_ using it, is confusing, to say the least.

Comment: So, some tips: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845). `sizeof(char)` is per definitionem 1. You probably want to copy the original string, use `strcpy`or `memcpy`. Don't `calloc` if `malloc` can do the job, the added zeroing costs some time.

Comment: `new_limit` is 0 because (as it happens) your newly allocated memory has a zero in its first place. Never mind that; you should not test it anyway, since you want `new_limit == limit`. By the way, you actually want `limit = strlen(str)+1`.

Comment: well, I changed it as you told me, now it return new_limit=24, and it should be 12

Comment: hi, I try to free the new_str in main, I have an Error :
Debug Error!
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED:after normal block(#60) at 0x008A7510
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer,

any help ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 new_str = (char*)calloc(limit, sizeof(char));
```

to

```
new_str = malloc(limit + 1);
strcpy(new_str, str);
```

You never copied the old string into the buffer you just made, so when you do `strlen` on it, of course you get zero.

Answer (score 0):

To malloc() string in c with the same size of original string, the function 'testCode' must be given one additional item of information.  Namely, the size of the original string.

```
#define SIZE_STRING 100
typedef char string[SIZE_STRING];

char *testCode(string str, size_t strSize)
```

Added 'strSize' (above) to the arguments of 'testCode' to provide the actual size of 'str'.

```
   {   
   char *new_str;
// int limit = strlen(str);
// int new_limit;
   new_str = (char*)calloc(strSize, sizeof(char));
```

Exchanged 'limit' for 'strSize' in order to allocate the correct size.

```
   new_limit = strSize;
```

Exchanged 'strlen(new_str)' for 'strSize'.  The previous term 'strlen(new_str)' will always be zero due to calloc()'s 'zeroing-out the new memory' feature.

```
   printf("%d", new_limit);

  return new_str;
  }

void main()
   {
   char str[SIZE_STRING] = { "BLA BLA BLA" };
   char *new_str;
   new_str=testCode(str, sizeof(str));
  }
```

A final thought...

The question was how to "malloc string in c with the same size of original string".  Keep in mind that the 'size' of a character array differs from the 'length' of a character array.  While the 'size' of an array is defined as the number of bytes (or perhaps elements) that make up the entire array, the 'length' of a C string is the number of characters found in the array up to the terminating '\0' character.

Hence if the question was actually how to "malloc string in c with the same *length* of original string", the above answer would still apply, except for the line:

```
new_str=testCode(str, sizeof(str));
```

would have to be changed to:

```
new_str=testCode(str, strlen(str)+1);
```

Comment: You might want to point out that the allocated length is one too small in the original code (in the question); it has forgotten to allow for the terminating null.  It also seems odd to allocate the space without copying the string.  If you don't need to copy the string, then `malloc()` or `calloc()` does the job without any extra help.  However, that's a separate discussion, perhaps.

Comment: Using `strlen` is fine

Comment: first of all thank you all,
now,@Mahonri Moriancumer I'm not allow to change the title of the functions, so it should stay.
For all those who told me to use strcpy, well, who say I need to copy strings ?, I have some projects in my collage and one of them is allocating enough memory for the new string..
again, thanks to all of you,
the next problem is, I can't free the memory from the main...

 puts(new_str);
 free(new_str);
 puts(new_str);

the free(new_str) just get Error,

thankS !

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you were given task to reimplement strdup() libc function?

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strdup.c;h=cedffa0da2e7a94ea8b95e79af6a7a5d0d3236d9;hb=HEAD#l37